# Centering with Auto layout Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uilabel, autolayout

I'm developing a swift app, and I am designing the interface in interface builder in Xcode. My interface (which consists of two UILabels, looks fine in portrait mode, but looks awful in landscape mode.

The issue is that the labels won't stay centered, as I want them, when rotated. I used the following auto layout constraints:

```
Upper edge constraint: top layout guide 
Lower edge constraint: bottom layout guide
Right edge constraint: standard value
Left edge constraint: standard value
```

These settings must not be working, as the label doesn't stay centered when rotated. What are the proper constraints to use for auto layout to center this label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the required effect in interface builder, I would advise you to do it using programmatic auto layout constraint.

```
[self.view addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint
    constraintWithItem:self.view 
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
    toItem:"YOUR VIEW" 
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
    multiplier:1
    constant:0]];
```

The above NSLayoutAttributeCenterX attribute centred the "YOUR VIEW" horizontally. For vertical centred layout, you can do so by changing the attribute property to NSLayoutAttributeCenterY for both self.view and "YOUR VIEW".

Comment: thanks! A few questions - can I make the code center in both horizontal and vertical orientations at once? Also, where do I put the code above? Just under the IBoutlet, or somewhere else? Sorry, I'm just learning swift!

Comment: I am afraid you can't as fas as I know. You need to set the constraint twice for both horizontal and vertical centring. The code should be put in viewDidLoad method.